# Bootstrap popover datepicker is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, calendar, datepicker, popover

I'm trying to display calendar in the pop-over but my problem is that the calendar displays behind the pop-over rather then in it. Any ideas for how I can solve this?

My JavaScript:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '#popupDatepicker7', function () {  
    jQuery('#popupDatepicker7').datepick();  
});
```

My HTML code:

```html
<input type='text' name='expiry_date' required='required' class='form-control parsley-validated' value='' id='popupDatepicker7' placeholder='Expiry date'>
```

Comment: Dont know what calendar you are using, but obviously change the calendars main div z-index to something greater than 1010 (popovers default z-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the css property 'z-index' of calendar, make it greater than pop-over.